# Laravel project under Ubuntu with Docker returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: docker, apache-httpd

Starting point:

Laravel 9 application, which I want to work with Docker container, I have only the project folder and nothing else installed on my PC.

What I did:

I installed Docker (Docker Desktop), opened the main directory of the project and created two files **Dockerfile** and **docker-compose.yml**, which contain the following respectively:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

COPY . /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
RUN composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

EXPOSE 80
```

and:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: preporuka-app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    container_name: preporuka-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: preporuka-app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - app-network

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: preporuka-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: preporuka
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Through the console I executed the following commands:

1. `docker compose build`
2. `docker compose up -d`
3. `docker compose ps` (everything seemed OK)

After loading localhost in the browser I received "403 Forbidden"

I am sharing **additional information** with important things that may be the problem:

This is what the **000-default.conf** file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is what the `/public/.htacces`s file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is what the `directory permissions` look like in the main directory:

```
root@411ea0b6c2b4:/var/www/html# ls -l        
total 456
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root        350 Nov  7 12:37 000-default.conf
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root        799 Nov  7 10:36 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root       3977 Oct  1 17:36 README.md
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root        336 Nov  6 19:32 apache-config.conf
drwxr-xr-x  9 root     root       4096 Oct  6 19:47 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root       1686 Oct  1 17:36 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root       4096 Oct  1 17:36 bootstrap
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root       1881 Oct  1 17:36 composer.json
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root     305287 Nov  5 20:27 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root       4096 Oct  1 17:36 config
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root       4096 Oct  1 17:36 database
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root        815 Nov  7 11:09 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x 66 root     root       4096 Oct  4 09:23 node_modules
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root      72061 Oct  4 09:23 package-lock.json
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root        438 Oct  1 17:36 package.json
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root       1175 Oct  1 17:36 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data   4096 Nov  6 19:44 public
drwxr-xr-x  7 root     root       4096 Oct  1 17:36 resources
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root       4096 Oct  1 17:36 routes
drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 Oct  1 17:36 storage
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root          0 Oct 25 13:52 test.php
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root       4096 Oct  1 17:36 tests
drwxr-xr-x 39 root     root       4096 Nov  5 20:27 vendor
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root        781 Oct  1 17:36 vite.config.js
```